# Appending list of dicts with dicts from list (circular?)

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a list of dictionaries and search for a specific key. If the value of that key matches a specific value, another list of dictionaries is provided. I would like to append the original list of dictionaries with the new dictionaries.

```
def test():
    info = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '4'}]
    for item in info:
        if "1" in item['a']:
            info2 = [{'c': '1', 'd': '2'}, {'c': '3', 'd': '4'}]
            for dict in info2:
                info.append(dict)
```

I was hoping my above attempt would result in the original info list being as follows:

```
info = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '4'}, {'c': '1', 'd': '2'}, {'c': '3', 'd': '4'}]
```

however I just end up with `TypeErrors`:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: You are missing another to iterate over the dict (for key, val in item.items()) and the condition could be if val == "1"

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: I do not get a `TypeError` when I run your example.

Comment: Apologies for the missing info, this is a simplified version of a much more complex function. Devesh's answer solved my problem!

Comment: Regardless the [mcve] should reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code

- You are trying to modify the `info` list you are iterating on, instead you should iterate on the copy of `info` via `for item in info[:]:`
- You can change `item['a']` to `item.get('a')` to make sure getting item doesn't thwo an exception if the key is not present, and you can change in to equality
- You can add the dictionaries from `info2` list to `info` list by extend the list using `list.extend`

Then your updated code will be

```
def test():
    info = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '4'}]
    #Iterate on copy of info
    for item in info[:]:
        #If value of a equals 1
        if item.get('a') == '1':
            #Extend the original list
            info2 = [{'c': '1', 'd': '2'}, {'c': '3', 'd': '4'}]
            info.extend(info2)

    return info

print(test())
```

And the output will be

```
[
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, 
{'a': '3', 'b': '4'}, 
{'c': '1', 'd': '2'}, 
{'c': '3', 'd': '4'}
]
```

Comment: You are not treating the new dicts that are being added in runtime.